# Kendo Grid pre-filter with multicheckboxes

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik, telerik-grid

I have grid which I want to be filtered when user visit a page. It filters good but it does not check checkboxes. Why?

Here is [demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/OYIfE) where it does not work aswell as in my project. There is several commented lines which I have tried also to run, but nothing works.

```
filter: { logic: "or", 
    filters: [{ field: "ProductName", operator: "eq", value: "Chai" }]},
```

this lines correctly filers table but checkbox is not checked.

```
filter: { logic: "or", 
    filters: [{ field: "ProductName", operator: "eq", value: "Chai" },
              { field: "ProductName", operator: "eq", value: "Chang" }]},
```

this correctly filters table but again, checkboxes which should be checked are not.

```
filter: { logic: "or", 
    filters: [{ field: "ProductName", operator: "eq", value: function() { return "Chai"; }}]},
```

this does not work which is strange because in my project I have assigned function aswell and it already filters table correctly but does not check checkboxes. Anyway in Dojo it does not work at all - question is if it should or not.

```
filter: { logic: "or", 
    filters: [{ field: "ProductName", operator: "eq", value: function() { return ["Chai", "Chang"]; }}]},
```

Same problem like above. In my project it filters table by multiple values but here it does not work.

So my question is how can I pre-filter table to have checked all checkboxes which were selected?

Answer (score 0):

I made a correction there in the demo, 
http://dojo.telerik.com/OYIfE/3

Probably bad Configuration, you can see beter in :

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-filter

hope this helps

EDIT: problem was first "filter" must be "filters" like :

```
filters: { logic: "or", 

                       filters: [{ field: "ProductName", operator: "eq", value: function() { return ["Chai", "Chang"]; }}]
                       },
```

Comment: Thank you @Marco for answer. Anyway it is not working. In your example, you just filterech everything what starts with c, but still ... checkboxes are not checked in the filter. If I use code you provided, it will not filter anything [look here example](http://dojo.telerik.com/OYIfE/8). And also [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-filter.logic) they write that it cannot be "filters", but "filter is correct"

Comment: I found nothing that Ever Made up check the checkbox, when you read the datasource , I leave here only an example , but the filter function that did to the button will have to be made ​​at the end of the grid load , it is only a way to do. http://dojo.telerik.com/OYIfE/13